# Apache RewriteRule, directory update then remove trailing slash (beautify URL)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, clean-urls

Currently have two requirements

1. Rewrite /olddirectory/ to /newdirectory/
2. Rewrite /newdirectory/pagename-3049103/ to just /newdirectory/pagename/

I have achieved step #1 using the following:

```
RewriteRule ^olddirectory/(.*)$ newdirectory/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Need assistance in step #2

- The content is at /newdirectory/pagename-3049103/
- I want to clean the url and display as /newdirectory/pagename/

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In the first rule, you've specified a 301 client-side redirect. This is not mandatory and has the side efect of a second client-server round trip for every request.
If you don't mind the browser mantaining the old path (ie site/olddirectory/xxx) you can simply rewrite as:

```
RewriteRule ^olddirectory/(.*)$ newdirectory/$1
```

Also I've removed the [L] flag since it states that no futher rewriting will be done and I think you want to do at least another rewrite for the pagename

If the trailing number in pagename-3049103/ is allways the same, it's just:

```
RewriteRule ^/newdirectory/pagename/?$ /newdirectory/pagename-3049103/ [L]
```

but I suspect that the pagename is at the url so it's:

```
RewriteRule ^/newdirectory/$1/?$ /newdirectory/pagename-$1/ [L]
```

NOTE: Now you can add the [L] flag since it's the last rule to be computed

Comment: For the training number, I want to remove it altogether. So,  "/newdirectory/pagename-3049103/" will just be "/newdirectory/pagename/"

Comment: If the number is allways the same, the first rule i propose is the one you need